# How to get a name of control by name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple function where there's a combo box. If combo box's value is equal to "Disable", I'll disable textbox B. There are many combo boxes with their corresponding textbox B, arranged in rows and named by hand. If combo box A is named `Product1`, textbox B will be named `Product1_status`

I was thinking something like:

```
If value_of_a = "disable" Then 
 Dim name_of_b as String
 name_of_b = Me.Combo.Name + "_status"
 get_object_by_name(name_of_b).Enabled = False
End If
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are calling this, but here's a self-contained procedure that should help:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ProductCombo As OLEObject
Dim ProductText As OLEObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
With ws
    Set ProductCombo = .OLEObjects("Product1")
    Set ProductText = .OLEObjects(ProductCombo.Name & "_status")
    ProductText.Enabled = ProductCombo.Object.Text <> "Disabled"
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: I really hate worksheet controls - I start from scratch every time I program them!  Nonetheless, I thought I'd add this subroutine which resets every textbox whose name fits the patter Product#_status, according to its paired combobox.  The logic does assume the names start with Product1, Product2, etc., without a gap in the numbering:

```
Sub test2()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ctl As OLEObject
Dim i As Long
Dim ProductComboboxesCount
Dim ProductCombo As OLEObject
Dim ProductText As OLEObject
Const ControlPrefix As String = "Product"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
With ws
    For Each ctl In .OLEObjects
        If TypeOf ctl.Object Is MSForms.ComboBox And Left(ctl.Name, Len(ControlPrefix)) = ControlPrefix Then
            ProductComboboxesCount = ProductComboboxesCount + 1
        End If
    Next ctl
    For i = 1 To ProductComboboxesCount
        Set ProductCombo = .OLEObjects(ControlPrefix & i)
        Set ProductText = .OLEObjects(ControlPrefix & i & "_status")
        ProductText.Enabled = ProductCombo.Object.Text <> "Disabled"
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It's great. Just FYI, my girlfriend's project mates basically just used ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("name_of_target_control") to get the contro and assume that's the correct one. -_-

Answer (score 3):

### VBA

Edit: (Change for an actual VBA macro)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' GetControl By Name
'
    If value_of_a = "disable" Then
        GetControl(ComboBox1.Name + "_status").Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub

Function GetControl(nameOfControl As String) As OLEObject
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject

    For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If ctrl.Name = nameOfControl Then
            Set GetControl = ctrl
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Function
```

---

### VB.Net

Code for VB.Net if anyone wants it for that reason:

```
Sub Main()
    If value_of_a = "disable" Then 
        GetControl(ComboBox_1.Name + "_status").Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Function GetControl(nameOfControl As String) As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If ctrl.Name = nameOfControl Then
            Return ctrl
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: VBA doesn't use `Return` - the VBA equivalent would be `Set GetControl = ctrl`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find that both answers largely what I wanted to do, just that Doug's one mirror my scenario more closely.